# Wrong MYSQL result

Tags: mysql

I have a var_dumped query here which displays a wrong result.

```
select p.*
, case when p.specials_new_products_price >= 0.0000 
  and (p.expires_date > Now() or p.expires_date IS NULL) 
  and p.status != 0 then 
      p.specials_new_products_price 
  else 
      p.products_price 
end price 

from wp_global_products_table p 
INNER JOIN wp_blogs s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id 
where p.products_name like '%indifi%' 
or p.products_description like '%indifi%' 
and s.countries_id = '168' 
and global_category_id = '15' 
and p.display_product = '1' 
and p.products_status = '1' 
order by p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name"
```

Here is the original query.

```
$catglobal_sql = "select p.*, case when p.specials_new_products_price >= 0.0000 and (p.expires_date > Now() or p.expires_date IS NULL or p.expires_date ='0000-00-00 00:00:00') and p.status != 0 then p.specials_new_products_price else p.products_price end price from ".TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS." p INNER JOIN ".TABLE_STORES." s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id where MATCH (p.products_name,p.products_description) AGAINST ('%".$search_key."%') ".$country_q." ".$zone." ".$currency_type." ".$search_cat." and p.display_product = '1' and p.products_status = '1' ".$duration." ".$product_type." ".$price_range." order by p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name";
if (!mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($catglobal_sql))) {
$catglobal_sql = "select p.*, case when p.specials_new_products_price >= 0.0000 and (p.expires_date > Now() or p.expires_date IS NULL) and p.status != 0 then p.specials_new_products_price else p.products_price end price from ".TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS." p INNER JOIN ".TABLE_STORES." s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id where p.products_name like '%".$search_key."%' or p.products_description like '%".$search_key."%' ".$country_q." ".$zone." ".$currency_type." ".$search_cat." and p.display_product = '1' and p.products_status = '1' ".$duration." ".$product_type." ".$price_range." order by p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name";
}
```

Say that, im searching "Indifi" which is available on the database, the Indifi's `global_category_id` has a value of 3.

As you can see on the var_dumped result, the `global_category_id` is 15 so "Indifi" should not be displayed however, it does.

What should be the problem on my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using brackets here:

```
...where (p.products_name like '%indifi%' 
or p.products_description like '%indifi%')
and s.countries_id = '168'
...
```

So that you're not `OR`-ing too much together.

Comment: I didn't saw that.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
where p.products_name like '%indifi%' OR p.products_description like '%indifi%' and s.countries_id = '168' and global_category_id = '15' and p.display_product = '1' and p.products_status = '1'
```

I see an `OR` there, so if `p.products_name like '%indifi%'`, then it doesn't matter what `global_category_id` is.

To fix precedence, use parentheses `(... OR ...)`.

Comment: I didn't saw that.. Thank you.